# manually renaming project in eclipse workspace

Tags: java, eclipse

I manually renamed project in work space rather than using refactor. I lost all files from that project folder. However, the new folder had created with the project name which I tried to rename with all files which i lost from original project folder which i renamed.So , I copied all files from new renamed project folder back to original project folder which I renamed .But ,I can't find any files in that original project folder in eclipse.

Comment: You have lost your metadata files that tell it that it belongs in the workspace the easiest way to do this is to use the import into workspace options.

Comment: @Sean F will you please tell me how to import metadata files into work space options

Comment: @user2737926 He meant import the new project into Eclipse, with Import->Existing project into workspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into the project folder, delete the .project and .classpath files, and the .settings folder. These contain outdated Eclipse-specific metadata, which is why Eclipse can't find your project.

Go back into Eclipse, and go File -> New project... -> Java project

If it's stored in your workspace, just type in the new path in the Name field;
If it's not stored in your workspace, untick "Use default path" and select the folder where your project is.

Et voila! Eclipse will generate new metadata, and all your source/binaries will still be present.